# Find the change-of-coordinate matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let F be the field with 4 elements, F={0,1,x,y}. Let $V=P_3(F)$ be the space of polynomials p(t) of degree ≤3. (We can't use x as the polynomial variable since it is already used as an element of the field F; so we use t instead.)

a) Find the Lagrange interpolation polynomials $p_i(t)∈V, i=0,1,2,3$ corresponding to

$c_0=0, c_1=1, c_2=x, c_3=y$.

b) Consider the two bases of V given by

β={$1,t,t^2,t^3$}$,   γ={p_0(t),p_1(t),p_2(t),p_3(t)}$
Find the change-of-coordinate matrices

$Q=[IV]^γ_β,   P=[IV]^β_γ$.

part a) i did$$\begin{bmatrix}0\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(0-1)(0-2)(0-3)} +1\frac{(x-0)(x-2)(x-3)}{(1-1)(1-2)(1-3)} +x\frac{(x-0)(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-2)(2-3)}+y\frac{(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)}{(3-1)(3-2)(3-3)}       \end{bmatrix}.$$ 
i have no idea abot part b, anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Note that as indicated by the problem, $t$ should be used for polynomial variable, not $x$ (since we already use $x$ for element in the field $F$).

I believe the problems in part (a) asks for four polynomials $p_i$ which form a (Lagrange) basis of $V$. In particular, $p_i(t)=\displaystyle\prod_{j=1,j\ne i}^3 \frac{t-c_j}{c_i-c_j}$. For example, $p_1(t)=\dfrac{(t-0)(t-x)(t-y)}{(1-0)(1-x)(1-y)}$ since $c_1=1$. (If you don't believe that these four are indeed a basis of $V$, you can try to prove it yourself or you can read the proof at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/501616/58951)). I don't think your answer for part (a) is correct.

For (b), the transition matrix from $\beta= (1,t,t^2,t^3)$ to $\beta'=(p_0(x),p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x))$ is exactly the Vandermonde matrix
$P_{\beta \to \beta'}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 \\
1 & y & y^2 & y^3  
\end{pmatrix}$. In particular if a polynomial $f(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3 \in V$
and $P_{\beta\to \beta'} (a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)^T=(b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ then 
$f(t)=b_0p_0(x)+b_1p_1(x)+b_2p_2(x)+b_3p_3(x)$.

In fact, $\boxed{b_i=f(a_i) \text{ for 
all } 0 \le i \le 3}$ (hint: what is $p_j(a_i)$ for each $0 \le i,j \le 3$),
which is the main reason why the above statement is true.