# Why evaluate polynomials when prove linear independence for Lagrange interpolating polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

From the proof in my text book and the accepted answer here: [Lagrange basis functions as bases of Polynomials Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501407/lagrange-basis-functions-as-bases-of-polynomials-space) , both proof substitute x with $a_i$, which would lead to $b_n = 0$ for i=n.

Then it concludes, “$b_1=b_2=…=b_n=0$“. Therefore, $g_i(x)$ are linearly independent.

From what I understand, the substitution, replacing x with $a_i$, and the evaluation, which gives $b_n=0$, establish the following,

When $x=a_1$, it has $b_1=0$; $x=a_2, b_2=0$;…$x=a_i,b_n=0$

To sum, when $x=a_i$, it has $b_n=0$ for
$$b_1g_1(x)+b_2g_2(x)+…+ b_ng_n(x)=0$$

My question is how does it reach the conclusion that for all x,
$$b_1=b_2=b_3=…=b_n=0$$
is the only solution in its null space?
It appears to me the proof is choosing a value for x and resolving a coefficient one at a time.

Comment: That step could be worded more clearly, as to avoid such misunderstandings. What it actually meant to say is that substituting $\,x=a_i\,$ gives $\,b_1 \cdot 0 + b_2 \cdot 0 + \dots + b_i \cdot 1 + \dots + b_n \cdot 0 = 0 \,$ $\,\implies b_i = 0\,$, and because this holds true for every $\,i\,$ it follows that $\,b_1=b_2=\dots=b_n=0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv So, in this case, the domain for x is $a_i$?

Comment: No, why? Try to work out a small example on paper, such as $n=3$, where the steps are easier to follow.